# R: take different variables from a row and make column header

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

```
rainfall <- data.frame("date" = rep(1:15),"location_code" = rep(6:8,5),
                       "rainfall"=runif(15, min=12, max=60))
rainfall30 <- rainfall %>%
  group_by(location_code) %>%
  filter(rainfall>30)
```

I want to use the above data to make the following table, is there a way to do it in R using dplyr?

```
date location6 location7 location8 
  2              47.7
  5              46.8
  6                         32.3
  7       55.3
  9                        40.5
```

I am just starting to use R, please apologize if this already answered. Thanks.

Comment: Do you need `tidyr::pivot_wider(rainfall30, names_from = location_code, values_from = rainfall)` ?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is `tidyr::pivot_wider`, which turns this long-form `data.frame` into a wide form. See [here](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pivot_wider.html) and [here](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/articles/pivot.html) for more information on pivoting data with `tidyr`.

```
rainfall30 %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = location_code,
              values_from = rainfall)

#     date   `6`   `7`   `8`
#    <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#  1     1  32.3  NA    NA  
#  2     2  NA    52.7  NA  
#  3     3  NA    NA    54.3
#  4     4  30.6  NA    NA  
#  5     7  52.4  NA    NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R option using `reshape` + `subset`

```
reshape(
  subset(rainfall, rainfall > 30),
  idvar = "date",
  timevar = "location_code",
  direction = "wide"
)
```

which gives something like below (using `set.seed(1)` to generate `rainfall`)

```
   date rainfall.8 rainfall.6 rainfall.7
3     3   39.49696         NA         NA
4     4         NA   55.59397         NA
6     6   55.12270         NA         NA
7     7         NA   57.34441         NA
8     8         NA         NA   43.71829
9     9   42.19747         NA         NA
13   13         NA   44.97710         NA
14   14         NA         NA   30.43698
15   15   48.95239         NA         NA
```